# Using WinRM with WSDL file?

Tags: windows, web-services, soap, wsdl, winrm

I'm interested in adding to an open source project or creating my own interface into windows remote management service from Python.However, it is difficult to create such a service when there is no web service description file (WSDL) to explain to me what functions and objects are available in the SOAP web service provided by Windows.

What is the WSDL file for WinRM? Or am I supposed to connect use WinRM without it?

Link to the question on the MSDN forum.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/772aa67f-fe95-488a-ab9a-6bde3a42658e/how-to-get-winrm-wsdl-file?forum=windowsserversolutionssdk

Comment: Revisiting this since I have time to work on the project again.  I don't think that this is off topic for stack overflow since the WSDL file is needed to understand how to improve, develop and code new features for a project that I am working on.  I'm not asking for an external resource, but how to request it from the windows remote management service since as a web service should have some level of self documentation. This is part of the SOAP web service work flow.  However, I could remove the external link to what's already been done on the microsoft side if needed.

Comment: I don't think it's off topic too.

Comment: I found https://github.com/ianclegg/winrmlib. It has WSDL in one of previous versions and, seemingly, it worked somehow. But author decided to switch to _requests_ and _xml2dict_. Not without a reason, probably...

Comment: And https://github.com/zenoss/txwinrm.

Answer (score 3):

It's available in the open specifications document MS-WSMV which describes WSMan in large detail. The full document can be downloaded from the MSDN site:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc251526.aspx

It is detailed in appendix A (Full WSDL):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd366131.aspx

All that can be provided is links as the full WSDL far exceeds the character limit allowed in a post.

This document contain some minor errors which can be spotted, for example, by PyCharm.

XSDs:

```
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer/transfer.xsd
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/eventing/eventing.xsd
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/enumeration/enumeration.xsd
```

Correct attribute names:

```
minOccurs
maxOccurs
processContents
```

`wsmanfault` namespace is not used.

Some attributes are set explicitly to their defaults.

Comment: I'm trying to use it today, so I'll keep the post updated.

Comment: Is there no way to directly request the WSDL file directly from a running windows RM server?  Almost all of the other web services will allow a client who is connecting to the service request the WSDL to know what functions are supported and how they operate.

Comment: @RustyWeber I haven't managed to make it work yet... Using `pywinrm` and code from Ansible...